# How to Kill an Exchange 2003 Session/Logon

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

In Exchange 2003 Under Administrative Groups::First Administrative Group:: Servers :: FooServer :: FooStorageGroup :: FooStore :: Logons there are sessions listed.

Is there an Exchange tool or third party tool that will let me kill specific sessions / logons?

Answer (score 1):

use Exchange User Monitor tool to find the IP address of client and then use TCPView tool to disconnect those sessions at individual IP level.

[ExMon](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Microsoft-Exchange-Server-User-Monitor.html)

[TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, should have stated that I tried TCPView and that it didn't work....

Comment: Can you elaborate on what didn't work with TCPView ? were you running it with Admin rights on the box ?

Comment: KAPes, been a while so I guess I missed your comment.  Yes, I am running with admin rights.  I tried right clicking the particular connection to store.exe and choosing 'close connection'.  This seems to have no effect.